# Where is --author at?

Tags: parity

After long days I have finally gotten **ethminer** and **Parity** to talk to each other!

However when I ask them to, Parity returns: Cannot give work package - no author is configured. Use `--author` to configure!

```
ethminer says:  ethminer  Getting work package...
JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Parity Wiki on GitHub:
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity
The `--author` argument is used to

> Specify the block author (aka "coinbase") address for sending block rewards from sealed blocks. NOTE: MINING WILL NOT WORK WITHOUT THIS OPTION. (default: None)

So basically you need to specify where to send block rewards. You should be able to fix the issue by editing your `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/config.toml` config file to include your desired author address.

You can also do this via console with `miner.setEtherbase(<desired address>)`

Comment: Thanks Eric, can you tell me where I get this value from? (sorry for the Newbish question)

Comment: No problem! Just set it to a wallet address that you want the block rewards sent to

Comment: Here's a crash course on accounts: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Accounts,-Wallets,-Vaults